# Joining contents of 2 columns

Tags: join

How do I join the content of two columns for the resulting column below:

```
Group:         Family:
polychaete     spionidae
gastropod      rossoidae
foraminifera   rotaliidae
polychaete     magelonidae
```

result needed:

```
Taxa:
polychaete_spionidae
gastropod_rossoidae
foraminifera_rotaliidae
polychaete_magelonidae
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Oracle, Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

In ANSI SQL, we can use the concatenation operator `||`:

```
SELECT "Group" || '_' || Family AS Taxa
FROM yourTable;
```

This would vary depending on the database.  For instance, SQL Server uses `+` as the concatenation operator.  Some databases have formal concatenation functions.

By the way, you should avoid naming your columns using SQL keywords like `Group`.